# Simple visualizations/drawings in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drawing, visualization

I want to generate simple drawings in my asp.net website based on some data I deal with in this application (I want to represent structure of Neural Networks). I know about existing System.Drawing namespace but Im curious if there are solutions more appropriate for asp.net.

It would be great if such visualization could be interactive (e.g. mouseover on some element displays extra infromation) but this is not necessay at the momment.

And idea or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is probably a good way to generate client-side visualizations, you can reuse most of the managed code knowledge you already have and there are several samples and controls that can help. 
No solution using just System.Drawing on the server-side will allow you to have client-side interactivity (potentially if you use maps, or ajax in conjunction you could), but at that point it might make more sense to use a Rich Framework, that is unless you are an expert in javascript.

Comment: Check something like: http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/gosilverlightdemo-silverlight-diagrams-35555/